# Change the processing mode to "routing-based" before adding system alias

Tags: odata, sap-gateway

While adding OData service from /IWFND/MAINT_SERVICE I get this error

> Change the processing mode to "routing-based" before adding system alias

I am trying to add a service locally pointing to the same system as the OData is existing in. Can someone help me with this error?

Comment: At what time this error throws? Before adding preventing you to add or after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be too late for an answer, but I was facing a similar error and since I found the fix, here it is.

OData services can be added in the transaction **/iwfnd/maint_service** with one of the 2 available Processing Modes,

1. Routing-based (default)
2. Co-deployed only

*Routing-based* is used where the frontend/gateway system is different from the backend. So if you choose this option, you must maintain a System Alias in the bottom right corner, for the respective service, even if the alias is LOCAL.

*Co-deployed only* as the name suggests, is used when the gateway and backend are "co-deployed", meaning the frontend/gateway is embedded into the backend. So if you choose this option, you don't even need to add a System Alias.

Here's the interesting part, if you choose 'Co-deployed only' and still maintain a System Alias, it is useless, as the OData service will call the service locally within the same system.

**Summary** - The reason why you get an error when you add a service, is because the system is telling you, make the service **Routing-based**, so that the alias you add has the necessary effect and doesn't just end up calling the service locally.

Here's where to change the Processing Mode. I've chosen the standard Fiori Launchpad service, INTEROP, as an example,

[Processing Mode for OData service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPzfX.png)

Here is some documentation - [SAP Gateway Foundation Co-Deployment SAP NW 7.51 SP08](https://help.sap.com/viewer/68bf513362174d54b58cddec28794093/7.51.8/en-US/0fc0a83349bc490aa1f36b420737c2f8.html)